# Compara datos en PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, crud

Me surge una duda, estoy haciendo una prueba de horarios para una escuela en donde junto la tablas, aulas ejemplo:

```
tabla aulas:
nombre             Oficina, 
codigo_aula        Isc-offi, 
ubicacion          Edificio A, 
altura             Planta-b, 
**capacidad          10**,
```

Y la tabla grupo:

```
clave_grupo      603-A, 
clave_carrera    ISC-1001, 
**numero_alumno    25**, 
periodo_grupo    2022-08-15, 
fin_periodo      2022-12-15,
```

Necesito que si el numero de alumnos es mayor a la capacidad, me mande una alerta de que no es posible añadir.

Anexo parte del INSERT:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $materia = $_POST["materia"];
    $profesor = $_POST["profesor"];
    $codigo_aula = $_POST["codigo_aula"];
    $clave_grupo = $_POST["clave_grupo"];

    do {
        if (empty($materia) || empty($profesor) || empty($codigo_aula) || empty($clave_grupo)) {
            $erroMessage = "Porfavor llene todos los campos";
            break;
        }
        $sql = "INSERT INTO clases (materia,profesor,codigo_aula,clave_grupo)" . "VALUES ('$materia', '$profesor','$codigo_aula','$clave_grupo')";
        $result = $cnn->query($sql);
        if (!$result) {
            $erroMessage = "Instancia invalida: " . $cnn->error;
            break;
        }

        //añadir nuevos datos
        $materia = "";
        $profesor = "";
        $codigo_aula = "";
        $clave_grupo = "";

        $succesMessage = "Se añadio correctamente";
        header("Location: gestion.php");
        exit;
    } while (false);
}
```

Comment: Estaría faltando que agregues en tu pregunta lo que has intentado. Por favor, [edit] tu pregunta y agrega el código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el POST veo que envías el código del aula y también la clave del grupo que guarda el numero de alumnos que tendrá o tiene ese grupo

```
$codigo_aula = $_POST["codigo_aula"];
$clave_grupo = $_POST["clave_grupo"];
```

Bien, antes del **do** que tienes debes hacer una consulta a cada una de las tablas **aulas y grupo** (ya que no están relacionadas). Guardas en una variable cada resultado y haces una condición que si el numero de alumnos es mayor que la capacidad te muestre el alert o lo que quieras...

```
SELECT capacidad FROM aulas Where codigo_aula = '$codigo_aula';
SELECT numero_alumno FROM grupo Where clave_grupo = '$clave_grupo';
// Guardas cada resultado en una variable
$capacidadAula;
$alumosGrupo;

if ($alumosGrupo > $capacidadAula) {
    # aca pones el alert o lo que sea
}
else{
    # el codigo que ya tienes y que guarda la clase
}
```

Comment: lo probare, muchas gracias

Comment: Si le funciona recuerde marcar la pregunta como resuelta :-)